# Convert.ToDecimal does not work with string "9.02"

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, decimal

I changed my whole app from "float" to decimal but in one point, I just cannot resolve this issue:

```
string a="9.02"

decimal d=Convert.ToDecimal(a);
```

It throws an exception, `incorrect input string format`. Why?

Comment: [It's all about the culture.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: I guess the default one. I have never changed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Convert.ToDecimal(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he38a8ca(v=vs.110).aspx) method uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) by default. Here how it's [implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#5c25d4c3f9036374);

```
public static decimal ToDecimal(String value)
{
   if (value == null)
       return 0m;
   return Decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Probably your `CurrentCulture`'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) is not `.` and that's why this method throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

As an alternative, you can use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) (which it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` is `.`) as a second parameter in your [`Convert.ToDecimal(String, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw(v=vs.110).aspx) method or you can [`Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone(v=vs.100).ASPX) your `CurrentCulture` and set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` propert to dot.

```
string a = "9.02";
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
string a = "9.02";
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(a, clone);
```